# Messaging between Parse users on iOS app

Tags: ios, parse-platform

On the iOS app that I am currently working on, I am having trouble making a user-to-user messaging system. I am using Parse, so I want the ability to have one Parse user send a private message to another Parse user. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: This is a very broad question. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High level answer since your question is very broad:
Create a message table on Parse, persist every message that a user sends to this table. Send push notification to the recipient user. On the recipient user's device, poll for messages from Parse with the appropriate query.
Again, this is just a starting point for you to think about the architecture of what you want to build.

Comment: Sorry for the broad question, but you answered it perfectly. Thanks for your help